# how to customize the display of a sfWidgetFormInputText?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4

i have this in RcProfileTableForm.class.php

```
abstract class BaseRcProfileTableForm extends BaseFormPropel
{
public function setup()
{
  $this->setWidgets(array(
  'id'                                => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
  'created_at'                        => new sfWidgetFormDateTime(),
  'name'                              => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'password'                          => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'unique_code'                       => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'msisdn'                            => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'profile_pic'                       => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'email'                             => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'age'                               => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
 )
}
```

and the form gets called like this:

```
<?php 
  include_partial('form', array('form' => $form));
  echo  $form->renderGlobalErrors(); ?>
```

so on the actual page it displays the label and the inputbox
what i need to do now is add a "*" to the end of the inputboxes of msisdn and email
the * will denote to a message appropriate to these fields

how can i achieve this? there is nowhere html that i can add a  to this because the whole form gets called from the widgets

any advice please?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form (RcProfileTableForm) you can add custom label

```
class  RcProfileTableForm extends BaseRcProfileTableForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
 $this->widgetSchema->setLabels(array(
  'email'    => 'email*',
}
// If you want to customize widget you can make:

 $this->widgetSchema['email'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array("style"=>'width: 290px;'));

));
```

// UPADATE

Read [**this**](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/03-Forms-for-web-Designers)

So you must customize your form partial in apps/frontend/yourmodules/template/_form.php

In _form.php I think you have now something like this:

You can make :

```
 <?php echo $form['email']->renderError(); ?>
 <?php echo $form['email']->render() ?> <?php echo  __("Email*"); ?> 
//or   
 <?php echo $form['email']->render() ?> $form['email']->renderLabel() ?>
```

Comment: thank you wanted to do it like that but the client want the "*" to appear AFTER the input box :(
was thinking of adding a class to it and in the CSS do a content: "*" but not quite working....the * is not displaying 
any other advice please?

Comment: thanks but i cannot have the * as part of the label, and my $form gets echoed all at once with one command: echo $form and as the fields are in the database so they are listed i need to try and customize the sfWidgetFormInputText with a class="do_asterisk" CSS i think

Comment: you must instead of echo $form  make like I said with email, and make it wit all fields of your form. If you want add class  `$this->widgetSchema['email'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array("class"=>'do_asterisk'));`

Comment: oooo ok i understand now..list all the fields in this way line per line as they must appear on the form, now i can manipulate each form item separately..one last thing, where do define 'do_asterisk'?? i have a .css file with the class do_asterisk but i have to include it somewhere so that _form.pgp knows to use it? how do i do that please? thanks

Comment: Yuo can include your css file in apps/frontend/config/view.yml in `stylesheets:[a.css]`